# Spacy Romanian language [W036] The component 'entity_ruler' does not have any patterns defined. error

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

After several long months of sneakily following you guys for troubleshooting tips, I finally came across a problem I didn't find a thread on (yet). I know it will probably be something stupid, but I can't wrap it up.

So here it is: I'm noobing my way around an awesome tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpyCzodvO3A) on creating a rudimentary Spacy training module containing an entity ruler and trying to test it. The language I'm working with is Romanian, maybe this has something to do with it. I can create it, load it but when I use it on a text it croaks on me.

The code below:

```
import spacy
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
from spacy.lang.ro import Romanian
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
import json
import os

def load_data(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data =json.load(f)
    return(data)

def generate_better_characters(file):
    data = load_data(file)
    print(len(data))
    new_characters = []
    for item in data:
        new_characters.append(item)
    for item in data:
        item = item.replace("și", "").replace("si", "").replace("Și", "")
        names = item.split()
        for name in names:
            name = name.strip()
            #   Debug
            #print(name)
            new_characters.append(name)
        if "(" in item:
            names = item.split("(")
            for name in names:
                name = name.replace(")", "").strip()
                new_characters.append(name)
        if "," in item:
            names = item.split(",")
            name = name.replace("și", "").replace("si", "").strip()
            #   Debug
            #print(name)
            if " " in name:
                new_names = name.split()
                for x in new_names:
                    new_characters.append(x)
                    #print(x)
            new_characters.apend(name)
    
    
    final_characters = []
    
    titles = ["Dr.", "Profesorul", "prof.", "Prof.", "Domnul", "domnul", "dl.", "Dl.", "Doamna", "doamna", "dna.", "domnisoara", "Domnisoara", "Dl. si dna."]
    
    for character in new_characters:
        if "" != character:
            final_characters.append(character)
            for title in titles:
                titled_char = f"{title} {character}"
                final_characters.append(titled_char)
    
    print(len(final_characters))
    final_characters = list(set(final_characters))
    print(len(final_characters))
    final_characters.sort()
    return(final_characters)

def create_training_data(file, type):
    data = generate_better_characters(file)
    patterns = []
    for item in data:
        pattern = {
                    "label": type,
                    "pattern": item
                    }
        patterns.append(pattern)
    return(patterns)

def generate_rules(patterns):
    nlp = Romanian()
    # Entity ruler is allowed to overwrite existing entries #
    ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
    ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
    nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
    nlp.to_disk("trained_ner")

patterns = create_training_data("C:\\tutorial.json", "PERSON")
generate_rules(patterns)

with open(f"C:\\mltutorial.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

nlp = spacy.load("trained_ner")
doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're following a spaCy v2 tutorial but using spaCy v3. The way `add_pipe` works changed significantly in v3.

```
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp) # this creates a ruler
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

# this creates a different ruler and adds it to the pipeline
nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler") 
nlp.to_disk("trained_ner")
```

In v2, the above code would have something like `nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", ruler)`. In v3 it instead returns the ruler object which you can then modify, like this:

```
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.to_disk("trained_ner")
```

Please [read the official spaCy docs on rule based matchers](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-usage).